# Bootstrap position layout error for medium screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive web site, where I'm facing a problem with medium screen.

To solve this problem I can't find why this problem occur?

In large screen I have image in left side & texts are in right side. 
But in medium screen text will be in left side & image will be in right side.

Don't know why this is happening?

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 blog_individual_post">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <img src="images/blog_dami.jpg" class="img-responsive img_space" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <p class="blog_post_title">Pizza</p>
        <p class="blog_post"> 

Pizza is an oven-baked flat bread generally topped with tomato sauce and cheese. It is commonly supplemented with a selection of meats, vegetables and condiments. The term was first recorded in the 10th century, in a Latin manuscript from Gaeta in Central Italy. The modern pizza was invented in Naples, Italy, and the dish and its variants have since become popular in many areas of the world.

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Large screen Image :
[image]

Medium Screen Image:
[image]

Comment: can you please provide the link to the live page/website.. It will be helpfull

Comment: Live Page : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86581418/consegna/blog.html

Comment: Check : resulation (1050 * 650) - (1190 * 650) pxl. You can check this with firefox

Comment: did you make any changes to the `bootstrap.css` file @line 1310 ` float: right;` it should be ` float: left;`

Comment: Thanks it works @ Manoj H L 2

Comment: Can you just help me one more thing. On live page you can see top nav is collapsed in xs/mobile size. But I want to collapsed it for medium & small screen also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p.s. Based on the [URL](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86581418/consegna/blog.html) you provided

```css
1389   .col-md-12 {
1390        float: right;
1391   }
```

It seams you have edited the `bootstrap.css` core file and made the `float: left` to `float: right`